# The wrong symbols inplace of Cyrillic in Rpres file (RStudio)

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a trouble - the presentation compiled in RStudio can't make the correct output. Instead of cyrillic symbols(Ukrainian/Russian) I have got smth from ASCII list (�).

Could you help me with cyrillic?
so far I have not found a clear hints how to remove this trouble.

PC:
win7 bit
RAM 8Gb
R 3.3.0 64bit
Rstudio - Version 0.99.486

Comment: try "save with encoding" (UTF-8) .. of it that doesn't help, update your knitr package and (maybe) R ... and if this doesn't help, try posting a small reproducible example. on my computer [LMDE, same version of Rstudio], cyrillic is rendered without problems in r presentations (just tried it).

Comment: @lebatsnok
Thanks for the nice hint - "save with encoding" (UTF-8)". It works :-) you can place it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "save with encoding" (UTF-8 or whatever is the right encoding).

You can also change the default encoding in Rstudio from `Tools --> Global options --> Default text encoding`.